# regular expression to rewrite 1x as x in mathematical expression

Tags: regex, math, text

I have texts that can contain mathematical expressions where 1x can occur, or more general, a 1 followed by a letter. What I'm trying to do is rewrite the math within the text with a regular expression so that all occurrences of 1x are replaced by x, but not so that ie. 21x becomes 2x. Also, the math within the text is within # delimiters and the 1x should only be replace when it is between the delimiters.

An example text is:

"As a 1st step, you can rewrite #21x*x - 1y# is equal to #1z + 1#"

this must become

"As a 1st step, you can rewrite #21x^2 - y# is equal to #z + 1#"

What I have so far as a regular expression pattern is

```
'/(#.*?)(\D?)1([a-z])(.*?#)/i'
```

and as a replacement

```
'$1$2$3$4'
```

but it does not do the job.
Any help on the pattern would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What language of regex are you using?

Comment: I'm using php as a language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example you gave, you could use this:

```
\b1([a-z])
```

And replace all occurrences/matches with `$1`.

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/pU3zK8).

EDIT: There was a misunderstanding with the question, so, a regex that can be used so that `1st` is not substituted as well:

```
\b1([a-z])(?=[^#]*#[^#]*(?:[^#]*#[^#]*#[^#]*)*$)
```

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/fE0bF7).

`(?=[^#]*#[^#]*(?:[^#]*#[^#]*#[^#]*)*$)` basically makes sure that there are an odd number of hashes ahead.

Comment: thanks, but the example did not come through correctly. It's a bit more complicated

Comment: @user761411 Do you have more than one equation per line? If you have only one, you could try [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/jC6aP9), which uses the regex `(?![^#]*#[^#]*#)\b1([a-z])(?=[^#]*#)`.

Comment: Yes, a lot more occurrences per line can occur.

Comment: @user761411 Another thing: you will probably require another separate function to replace the `x*x` by `x^2`. If you have only squares, you could do [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/bJ4xJ1). Otherwise, I don't think regex is the best way for this substitution.

Comment: Great stuff, indeed the delimiters come always in pairs, smart!

Comment: No, I don't need to rewrite the square, but there are other delimiters like the @ (where I can apply the same pattern) but also the two character \\(  \\). Any chance I can use a similar pattern for these?

Comment: @user761411 What do you mean by the 'two character'? Brackets? If they are not nested, it will be easier in fact, [like so](http://www.regex101.com/r/xZ2pG9).

Comment: Indeed, not nested, but like open =  \( and close is \)

Comment: @user761411 If you want an 'all in one' regex for `@`, `#` and `()`, you can use [this one](http://www.regex101.com/r/uG5hD1). If this suits you, I'll add it to my answer above.